# DIV does not move or scale via JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm getting started with an HTML 5 app. When my page loads, I have a logo in the center of the screen. I need the logo in the center of the screen to begin with. The user can begin using the app by clicking the "Begin" button. When this happens, I want to animate the logo in two ways:

1. I want the logo to move from its current location to the upper left corner (with a bit of padding from the top and left)
2. I want to scale the image down.

In an attempt to do this, I'm using JQuery UI. Here is what I currently have:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <input type='button' value='Begin' onclick='return beginButton_Click();' />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <span id="greeting" class="footer-content">
            Hello
        </span>
        <span class="separator">|</span>
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="footer-content">View Status</a>
    </div> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function beginButton_Click() {
        $("#load").animate({
          width: "30%",
          height: "30%",
          opacity: 0.4
        }, 1500);

      }
    </script>
</body>
```

My CSS is defined in another file. My CSS looks like this:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body, #footer {
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -34px;
    background-color: #4cff00;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background: transparent url(/images/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
}

#footer {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer-separator {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#info{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.footer-content, .action {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Currently, my logo div does not scale or move to the upper left. I can't figure out how to move the div because its relatively positioned. Yet, I need it in the middle of the screen. Beyond that, I have no idea why the div is not scaling. Can someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're doing HTML5, you should consider using [CSS animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) for this, and only use the jQuery as a polyfill for [old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=css3%20animation). Use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as a way to detect the browsersupport and conditionally load the extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `#load` to `#logo` to select that div in your jQuery selector for the animate call. In order to move it to the top left, you can use position() from jQuery UI.

```
$('#logo').animate({ /* your call here */ })
.position({ my: 'center', at: 'left top', of: document });
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `$("#load")` be `$("#logo")`?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo. Still, the #logo div disappears. It doesn't stay on visible.